# Chaning fill property in css using Javascript doesnt happen immediately

Tags: javascript, html, css, graph

im trying to make a graph alogrithms simulator. and so i want to change the color of the vertex which im currently on. this is my code:

```
vertices.forEach(function(source) {
      
    source.htmlElement.style.fill = color; 
    console.log("changing color...")
   sleep(1000); }//sleep is a blocking function i made
```

when doing so the console.log is displayed after 1 sec each time but the css is changed only after all of the vertices are done. why this happens? thanks!

Comment: how are you able to block it using sleep ? I can't think of any such way.

Comment: function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  }

Comment: That is a costly way of making it sleep. Prefer async/await instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this synchronously, because of the way main thread works.

Javascript being single-threaded, there is only one thread: [Main Thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread), which executes your javascript and paints.
Since your code is synchronous, the main thread is blocked by your code and it cannot paint the DOM during that.

Instead, you should use asynchronous functions like this.

```js
const vertices = document.querySelectorAll('.vertex');

async function sleepAsync(ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(), ms))
}

async function exec() {
  for(let v of vertices) {
    v.style.fill="green";
    await sleepAsync(500);
  }
}
exec()
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.vertex {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="vertex" >
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

For more information, read:

1. [Main Thread | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread)
2. [Asynchronous Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)
3. [General asynchronous programming concepts | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts)

Comment: thanks for the reply, im not quite sure why the dom cannt be painted on my code, the painting happens before sleep is blocking the main thread . thanks!

Comment: No. You change a css attribute before sleep. It will happen later, after all of your synchronous code is executed that real painting will be done.

Comment: In "real painting", the browser will read what attributes have changed and will draw the elements accordingly.